# Avoid reppetitive respond_to? calling

Tags: ruby, dry

I need to check whether a object respond to an arbitrary number of methods.

And i'm tired of doing this:

```
if a.respond_to?(:foo) && a.respond_to?(:bar) && a.respond_to?(:blah)
```

What would be a more "correct" DRY way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Typically, you want to know if it responds to something immediately before you call it.

Comment: good question. i asked it myself. unfortunately i have to do this as i'm fixing some indish/pakistanish code and there are a lot of "undocumented features" like crazy spaghetti inheritance and where ducks behaves like goats. the only way to deal with this is to ask each object what is it and what it can do.

Comment: There's almost always a better way to do it. Have a look at Avdi Grimm's work on Confident Code ( I think you can find a conference videos, slideshows, books, etc. that he's done on this topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if you have nothing against monkeypatching:

```
class Object
  def respond_to_all? *meths
    meths.all? { |m| self.respond_to?(m) }
  end

  def respond_to_any? *meths
    meths.any? { |m| self.respond_to?(m) }
  end
end

p 'a'.respond_to_all? :upcase, :downcase, :capitalize
#=> true

p 'a'.respond_to_all? :upcase, :downcase, :blah
#=> false

p 'a'.respond_to_any? :upcase, :downcase, :blah
#=> true

p 'a'.respond_to_any? :upcaze, :downcaze, :blah
#=> false
```

**UPDATE:** using `meths.all?` and `meths.any?`. @MarkThomas, thanks for refreshing my mind.

**UPDATE:** fixing `responsd` typo.

Comment: Your names are a hint that you should use the `Enumerable` methods `all?` and `any?` in the implementation...

Comment: nice! i wonder why i could not do this myself... i'm feeling stupid :) thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can always wrap it in a helper method:

```
def has_methods?(obj, *methods)
   methods.all?{|method| obj.respond_to? method}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Active Support` extension from `Rails`.
It has method [try](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#try). It's hard to say how you can use this method because of lack of context, maybe something like this:

```
if a.try(:foo) && a.try(:bar) && a.try(:blah)
```

In order to use this method you should

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb'
```

Also check my version of this method the [tryit](https://github.com/sevenmaxis/tryit):

Comment: thank you for answer, however i hate Active* and any other bloated Rails s(hit)tuff :)

Answer (score 0):

The 'correct' way (or one of many, anyway), is Tell Don't Ask, meaning that if you're sending the object a message, you expect it to respond without complaining. This is also known as Duck Typing (if it can quack, it's a duck).

I can't give you any specific advice, because you haven't asked a specific question. If you're testing for three different methods it seems like you don't know what kind of object `a` is, which can be an interesting case to deal with. Post more code!

Comment: totally agree about "Tell Don't Ask", but... see my comment to my question